# How to quickly remove Sun Tan?

Tags: personal-care

I need a way to remove sun tan quickly, I'm a cricket player and i play cricket match every weekend whenever i come back from a cricket match, color of my face and neck turns totally different from color of  my body just because of sun tan. and it looks disgusting.
**Is there any way to quickly remove Sun Tan?** i want to get it done like in few hours. Please only give home remedies because medical creams can damage my skin.

But.
After few days, my skin automatically turns but i want to remove sun tan,the same day.

Comment: Do you mean sun tan? Which is where your skin produces melanin and gets darker from exposure to UV. Or do you mean sun cream, sun blocker or maybe fake tan products?

Comment: Yes i mean sun tan, i live in Pakistan, and temperature in my city stays like 25-35 in between 12-3pm. Yes, i used sun block few times but my skins start burning after applying it.

Answer (score 4):

You can't remove the melanin from your skin.

But you can (and should) prevent the sun from shining on it. Use sun-blocker (experiment till you find a brand you like), or a hat.

You see a lot of cricketers wearing caps. There are even special hats with flaps at the back, to protect the neck. You can also wear a shirt with a collar and turn it up to protect your neck.

Answer (score 0):

Based on my personal experience as I often do tracking:

- Apply aloe vera gel on affected area and keep all over night
- I also apply curd on affected area about 15-20 mins
- You can also apply curd-besan-haldi pack once in week and its work like charm